# Named associations with sequelize.js

Tags: sequelize.js

This seems to create *one* column `roomId`

```
Room.hasMany(Room.);
Room.belongsTo(Room);
```

This creates the columns `parentId` and `roomId`

```
Room.hasMany(Room);
Room.belongsTo(Room, {as:'parent'});
```

This throws an error:

```
Room.hasMany(Room, {foreignKey:'parent'});
Room.belongsTo(Room, {as:'parent'});
```

I expected it to work like the first example, but with different column title.

**Background:**

Since it is a simple one-to-many association I only want one column.

I want to query with `Room.findAll({where:{parentId:123}})` and use `getParent()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Room.hasMany(Room, { foreignKey: 'parentId' );
Room.belongsTo(Room, { foreignKey: 'parentId', as:'parent' });
```